# How to make screen client updates whenever an event occurred (MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, event-handling

I'am new in MVC. I'am currently working to transform a desktop to a web application.

I need to make an update to the user view when an event of an object occurred. I have an object that observe a humidity sensor. Let say This object will trigger an event when the humidity above 70%. The code might be like this:

```
Private Sub Humidity_Alert(sender As Object) Handles objSensor.Alert
    'Update user chart
End Sub
```

In desktop application, I just make an update to the view as usual in realtime, but I don't have any idea yet how to return this event to the client in MVC, without using javascript timer to make an ajax call to request if there is any alert. How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using ASP.NET SignalR library: [signalr.net](http://signalr.net/)

You can use it for real-time updates from server to client.

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

Some pseudo-code example:

SignalR Hub:

```
public class HumidityHub : Hub
{
    public void RefreshChart(string data)
    {
        Clients.All.refreshChart(data);
    }
}
```

ClientCode:

```
var hub = $.connection.humidityHub;

hub.client.refreshChart= function (data) {
    //refresh your chart    
};

$.connection.hub.start();
```

ServerCode:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HumidityHub >();
hubContext.Clients.All.refreshChart(data);
```